# Hide/Disable Weekends from Kendo UI dateTimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, datetimepicker

I am using [kendo DateTimePicker](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datetimepicker/template.html) and just don't want user to select from Weekends.

I have tried assigning MonthTemplate() aproach as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => Data)
                       .MonthTemplate("# if (isWeekDay(data.date)) { #" +
                                                    "#= data.value #" +
                                                    "# } #" 
                                                    )  
    function isWeekDay(date)
        {
            var day = date.getDay();

            return (day % 6 != 0);
        }
```

But it helped me for just not displaying the Date in the Widget, but user still able to select it by clicking over the blank Cell in the Month Template.

Tried using Validation handling onChange Event and (e.StopPropagation for not closing the dropdown), but still its working.

Is it possible or doing efforts invain?

Thanks 
Sumeet

Comment: Looking for something like we have in Jquery dateTimepicker:  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });

Comment: Friends, is somethign wrong with my question. Its been more than 24 hrs and this is not able to catch even a single attention? Am I doing things completely wrong or there is something wrong in stating my problem. Please guide me..

Answer (score 6):

Hope you still need help about your question.
This is a way to disable click on weekends.

```
.kendoDatePicker({
    open: function() { $('.k-weekend a').bind('click', function() { return false; }); }
});
```

.k-weekend is the class associated to weekend cells. So, it's easy to disable the click on those cells. It's also possible to put some CSS to change the aspect of those cells.

Hope this will help.
Laurent